# What Is Dolphin?

Tags: dolphin

I am using Ubuntu 12.04LTS and I was just going through the applications scope and I saw an application called dolphin and it looked like the home folder(nautilus file manager). So when I opened it the heading was jatin - 'Dolphin'. and it looked like this

[image]

Can anyone tell me what it is?

I am new to Ubuntu and I don't know much terms so please try and explain in easy language.

Comment: IMO Dolphin is just as good, if not better than Nautilus. You didn't happen to install KDE, did you?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolphin_%28file_manager%29

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A file manager is software which provides a user interface to assist in the organisation of files.

Every file manager provides basic operations such as to create, open, view, edit, search, rename, move copy, and delete files. However, file managers typically come supplied with sophisticated functionality including network connectivity, directory synchronizing, archive handling, advanced searching, shortcuts, file/folder comparisons, checksums, plugins, and more, making them an incredibly powerful tool.

Dolphin is a file manager focusing on usability. You can browse, locate, open, copy and move files with it.

It is the default file manager for the current version of KDE (KDE 4), and can be optionally installed on KDE 3.

**Features include:**

- Sidebar
- Supports dockable panels for places, information, folders and a
  terminal
- Breadcrumb Navigation bar for URLs which allows users to navigate
  quickly through the file hierarchy
- 3 view modes (icon, list and column) with properties remembered for
  each folder
- Split views designed for file copy- and move-operations
- Network transparency
- Undo/redo functionality
- Support of service menus
- Zoom from 16 x 16 pixels to 256 x 256 pixels
- Tooltips show previews
- Thumbnails
- Panel tabs
- Renaming of a variable number of selected items in one step
- Supports: SMB/CIFS, WebDAV, NFS, FTP, and SSH
- Networked Environment for Personalized, Ontology-based Management of
  Unified Knowledge (NEPOMUK) integration

[image]

[More information about.](http://userbase.kde.org/Dolphin/File_Management#General_information)

[source](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20081224191928555/FileManagers.html)

**To install dolphin in Ubuntu:**

Open a terminal,using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get install dolphin
```

**To make dolphin default file manager instead of Nautilus**

1. Open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Install `exo-utils` by running the following command in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install exo-utils
   ```
3. Run the following command in the terminal:

   ```
   exo-preferred-applications
   ```
4. In the window that opens, click on *Utilities*
5. On the *File Manager* section, click the drop-down menu arrow + Other...
6. Find `/usr/share/applications` directory
7. Adjust to show all files and select `dolphin.desktop` (wherever you find it)
8. Click *close*

Comment: could this answer be updated for ubuntu 18 & 19 please?

Answer (score 2):

Dolphin is a simple file manager, like Nautilus, but it is default in Kubuntu.

[Project page](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/dolphin/)

> Dolphin is the default file manager in the KDE Plasma Workspaces, intended to be both powerful and easy to use.
>
> Features include:
>
> - Customisable sidebars
> - "Breadcrumb" navigation
> - View properties remembered for each folder
> - Split views
> - Network transparency
> - Undo/redo functionality
> - Ratings, comments, and tags
>
> This package is part of the KDE base applications module.
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

### In a Nutshell

Dolphin is a file manager, like Windows Explorer. The default file manager on Ubuntu is nautilus from the Gnome desktop. Dolphin is from the KDE desktop. (You'll notice that it uses different icons and colours.)

[Many file managers exist](http://www.tuxarena.com/2011/06/20-file-managers-for-ubuntu/), also ones running in the  terminal like midnight commander. Those are especially useful when you log in to a remote PC/Server via terminal, i.e. text only.