# Problem installing dolphin file manager

Tags: unity, filemanager, dolphin

I am trying to install dolphin file manager in my ubuntu 17. So I was following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429705/what-is-dolphin). But when I run this `exo-preferred-applications` in terminal I get this message

```
/usr/bin/exo-preferred-applications: 11: exec: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/exo-1/exo-helper-1: not found
```

I want to set dolphin as my default file manager. So how can I do this? I am using ubuntu 17 and unity 7.5

Comment: Have you had a look [over here?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager)

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution ?

Comment: It didn't work for me. Still using nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message in xfce4.

The error message says that this file is missing. So I had a look at which package provides this file and install it.

```
$ apt-file search exo-helper-1
libexo-1-0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/exo-1/exo-helper-1
$ sudo apt-get install libexo-1-0
```

Now the message is gone.

However I am still encountering other errors in other places, so I guess either I can reinstall the whole desktop, or work through them one by one, or just ignore them.

I use `apt-file` above, which you can install:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
```